# Не добавляются option в select через ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть `select` с `id` `urlHost`. Вот таким кодом я хочу добавить опций к нему:

```
var fillSelect = function (selectName, listOfValues) {

    $.each(listOfValues, function(key, value) {
        $('#' + selectName)
            .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value",value)
                .text(value));
    });
};

$.ajax({
    url: "/event/data/hosts",
    context: document.body
    // async: false
}).done(function(data) {
    if (data.result === 'success') {
        data = data.data;
        console.log(data);

        fillSelect('urlHost', data);

    }
});
```

Проблема в том, что данный код срабатывает только после выставления параметра `async` в `false`.

Comment: как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: @Igor очевидно выполняя что-то в цикле)

Comment: @Igor, в смысле ? Ставлю `async: false` и появляется `select` с кучей опций. Если не поставить, то получится пустой `select`.

Comment: при закомментированном `async: false`,  `console.log(data);` - выводит что-нибудь в консоль?

Comment: @Igor, да. Происходит подключение к базе данных и информация по логам забирается с сервера, но в `select` не попадает. :(

Comment: при чем здесь подключение к базе данных? В консоли браузера что появляется?

Comment: @Igor, ничего не появляется. Ошибок нет.

Comment: используйте `success: ` и `error: ` обработчики в опциях `$.ajax`